# How to check if web browser support OpenGl using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, opengl, opengl-es

[Accordin to this:](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/coding/3D-graphics)

> Vetting the driver in JavaScript
>   At startup, the application should perform a few additional tests that can be implemented in JavaScript on its hosting web page. The script that performs these tests should be included before the module’s embed tag, and ideally the embed tag should appear on the hosting page only if these tests succeed.
>   The first thing to check is whether you can create a graphics context. If you can, use the context to confirm the existence of any required OpenGL ES 2.0 extensions. You may want to refer to the extension registry and include vendor prefixes when checking for extensions.
>
> Once you’ve passed the JavaScript validation tests, it’s safe to add a Native Client embed tag to the hosting web page and load the module.

There is possibility to create script which checks if web browser supports OpenGL, but I can't find any information how to do it. How should I check if web browser support OpenGl (not WebGl)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Modernizr](http://new.modernizr.com/docs/)?

> Detects support for OpenGL extensions in WebGL. It's true if the WebGL extensions API is supported, then exposes the supported extensions as subproperties, e.g.:
>
> > if (Modernizr.webglextensions) {
> >       // WebGL extensions API supported
> >     }
> >     if ('OES_vertex_array_object' in Modernizr.webglextensions) {
> >       // Vertex Array Objects extension supported
> >     }

Comment: I have added modernizr to my project and I don't have an access to webglextensions properties...